# htaccess: Why 301 redirect doesn't work for single page but works for all pages in general?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

It works for all page:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.ru/somepage/ [R=301,L]
```

But I would like to redirect single page. This code doesn't do redirect:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^thePageOnOldDomain.php?someGetParameter=1 http://www.newdomain.ru/somepage/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the ?) In a rewrite rule. Use the %{QUERY_STRING} various

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} someGetParameter=1
RewriteRule ^someoldpage.php$ http://newdomain.ru/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thx, it works! but I get http://newdomain.ru/?someGetParameter=1 instead of http://newdomain.ru/ in this case